# ES6 React property is undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, babeljs

I'm trying to get to work [this code](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/eZwZdw).

```
/*
 * A simple React component
 */
class Application extends React.Component {
    num = 42;
    render() {
      return (
        <button onClick={this.show}>show</button>
      );
    }
    componentDidMount() {
      console.log(this.num);
    }
    show() {
      console.log(this.num);
    }
}

/*
 * Render the above component into the div#app
 */
React.render(<Application />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

The problem is, when I click the button to get the property's value, it will be undefined. The interesting part is that the `ComponentDidMount()` function can access the `num` value.

I think that the `show()` function has different context, and that's why I can't refer to `num` via `this` keyword. I tried to bind the `num` value in the constructor, but it didn't work either, so I removed it.

Any idea how can I get the `num` value by clicking on the button?

Comment: Related: [How to access the correct `this` / context inside a callback?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20279484/218196)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use either an arrow function

```
<button onClick={() => this.show()}>show</button>
```

or bind the value of `this`

```
<button onClick={this.show.bind(this)}>show</button>
```

to get the correct `num`

Ref:

Arrow functions: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

Function.bind: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using ES6 syntax, React doesn't autobind this to your method see :

https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/reusable-components.html#no-autobinding

And for more way to do this binding see this :

http://egorsmirnov.me/2015/08/16/react-and-es6-part3.html

edit : accepted answer provide bad practice see this : https://daveceddia.com/avoid-bind-when-passing-props/

Answer (score 0):

You are right - the `show` function has a different context.

You can solve solve this by binding the context to the `onClick` callback:

`<button onClick={this.show.bind(this)}>show</button>`